# Hasura - "Looks like you do not have any tables"

Tags: postgresql, hasura

I have a Postgres Database with tables in it and they don't show up in Hasura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably untracked, you need to go to `data` and `Untracked tables or views` and click `track all`.
More documentation [here](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/schema/using-existing-database.html#step-1-track-tables-views)

Answer (score 1):

I've hit this issue in an RDS setup when I had tables that were owned by a postgres user that was not the user given to Hasura.

Check the tables in pgadmin to see the ownership and test by creating a new table using the user that you provided to the Hasura container.

Hope this helps
Cheers